# Как инвертировать регистр символов всего предложения?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Не могу втолковать как с помощью регулярки инвертировать регистр символов. На данном этапе меняет регистры всех символов, а надо что бы менял регистр только в подборке. Что нужно изменить??

***Задание***
Создать класс, который выводит содержимое текстового файла в консоль, 
инвертируя регистр всех символов каждого слова, которое содержит более 3 символов.

> ***В файле part1.txt лежит***
>   When I was younger
>   So much younger
>   Than today
>   Информацию из файла
>   в верхний регистр

**part1.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Part1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(mainMethod(Util.readFile("part1.txt")));
    }

    public static String mainMethod(String input) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{4,}+|[А-Яа-яёЁ]{4,}+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            char c = chars[i];
            if (m.find(0)) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(c) || chars.length <= 4) {
                    chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
                } else {
                    chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                }
            }
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }
}
```

**Util.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Util {

    private static final String ENCODING = "Cp1251";


    public static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(bytes, ENCODING);
    }

    public static Matcher getMatcher(String regex, String input) {
        return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/iDQf5R

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String s = "When I was younger\nSo much younger\nThan today\nИнформацию из файла\nв верхний регистр";

    char chs[] = s.toCharArray();

    for (int q=0; q<chs.length; ++q) {
      chs[q] = Character.isUpperCase(chs[q]) ? Character.toLowerCase(chs[q]) : Character.toUpperCase(chs[q]);
    }

    String res = new String(chs);

    System.out.println(res);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Part1 {

    public static String convert(String input) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\p{L}{4,}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            char[] array = sb.substring(m.start(), m.end()).toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(array[i])) {
                    sb.setCharAt(m.start() + i, Character.toLowerCase(array[i]));
                } else {
                    sb.setCharAt(m.start() + i, Character.toUpperCase(array[i]));
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convert(Util.readFile("part1.txt")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String mainMethod(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{4,}+|[А-Яа-яёЁ]{4,}+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input.length());
    while (m.find()) {
        char[] chars = m.group(1).toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            char c = chars[i];
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            } else {
                chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            }
        }
        m.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(chars));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```